# Accessing getter for an object that is part of a vector contained in separate class

Tags: class, object, pointers, vector, getter

I'm trying to figure out how to use a getter function with a particular object that is contained within a vector that is in a separate class. Ok, there's a class Patron that contains GetNumBooks(), and there's a class PatronList that contains vector patrons, how would I within class Loan call GetNumBooks(for a patron object within vector patrons) in a conditional?

Loan class:
https://pastebin.com/1KSKFvmS
Patron class:
https://pastebin.com/F7amyfHb
PatronList class:
https://pastebin.com/8ARsHQQy

I've tried the following:

in PatronList:

```
vector<Patron>* ReturnVec(){
       vector<Patron>* PatPtr = new vector<Patron>;
        PatPtr = &patrons;
       return PatPtr;
       
      }
```

in Loan:

```
void Loan::Test(Patron myPatron){
 vector<Patron>* here = new vector<Patron>;
  here = list.ReturnVec();
  here->push_back(myPatron);
  here->at(0).SetNumBooks(11);
  cout << here->at(0).GetNumBooks();
}
```

Which seems to work but...I suppose I want to know if there's a better solution. Are pointers even necessary? If so, do I really need to declare a pointer in both Test *and* ReturnVec?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use raw-pointers and `new vector<Patron>` here - [you can allocate it locally and return it by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704565/efficient-way-to-return-a-stdvector-in-c) - in fact, you should entirely avoid using raw pointers: C++ is not C.